# How to extract pixel value corresponds to a 2D image point represented by (x,y) coordinate?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to implement a space carving algorithm to reconstruct 3D shape of a moving person. I have all the camera calibration data and projection matrices. Also I could get 2D image points from the 3D world coordinate system using the following steps:

```
                    i = 1;                    
                x = P * [ X Y Z 1 ]';
                 u(i) = x(1)/x(3);
                 v(i) = x(2)/x(3);
```

where P is the projection matrix, [ X Y Z 1 ] is the 3D world coordinate system.

u & v represents the mapped 2D image points. I'm getting example values u=8.51e+02 and v=8.33e+02.

The question is how I can check what is the pixel intensity value corresponds to point (u,v)?

Comment: Your question is not clear! You want the value of your_image(851,833)?!

Comment: What is the name of your image? what's the dimension of that image?